# Group invariants of tensor product of modules when one module is projective and one action is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, representation-theory

I am trying to check if the following statement is  true

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ a $R-$module. 
>   Suppose that $G$ is a group acting on $M$ by $R-$linear
>   automorphisms. Let $N$ be a projective $R-$module. Suppose that $G$ acts
>   on $M\otimes_{R}N$ by the formula
>   $$
> g(m\otimes n)=g(m)\otimes n 
> $$
>   for all $g\in G, m\in M$ and $n\in N$. Then
>   $$
> (M\otimes_{R}N)^G=M^{G}\otimes_{R} N.
> $$

Here is what I believe that should be a good solution of the claim:

> Using the projectivity of $N$, let $P$ be a $R-$module such that $N\oplus P\cong R^{\oplus S}$ for some
>   set $S$. The isomorphisms
>   $$
> M\otimes_{R}(N\oplus P)\cong M\otimes_{R}R^{\oplus S}\cong M^{\oplus S} 
> $$
>   are $G-$equivariant where we define the actions $G$ on $M\otimes_{R}(N\oplus P)$
>   and $M\otimes_{R}P$ in analogous way to the one on $M\otimes_{R}N$. Taking $G-$invariants in the above
>   isomorphisms we obtain
>   $$
> (M^{G})^{\oplus S}= (M^{\oplus S})^G\cong \big(M\otimes_{R}(N\oplus P)\big)^G
> \cong (M\otimes_{R}N)^G\oplus (M\otimes_{R}P)^G
> $$
>   Using the flatness of $N$ and $P$ over $R$ we have that $M^G\otimes_{R}N$
>   and $M^G\otimes_{R}P$ are contained in $M\otimes_{R}N$ and $M\otimes_{R}P$,
>   respectively. It is also clear that $M^G\otimes_{R}N\subseteq (M\otimes_{R}N)^G$
>   and $M^G\otimes_{R}P\subseteq (M\otimes_{R}P)^G$ hold by definition. Hence
>   $$
> (M^{G})^{\oplus S}= (M^G \otimes N)\oplus (M^G \otimes P)\subseteq 
>  (M\otimes_{R}N)^G \oplus (M\otimes_{R}P)^G=(M^{G})^{\oplus S}
> $$
>   Therefore all of the inclusions must be equalities and the result follows.

Can anyone tell me if there is anything wrong with it?